# Get Site URL stored in solution properties SiteURL

Tags: c#, url, sharepoint

Currently working on creating custom function for a `SharePoint` site, i have inserted `Site URL` on the `SharePoint` project folder, is it possible i retrieve the `Site URL` from the project properties to use in `.cs` file within it?

[image]

Comment: Please try `SPContext.Current.Site.Url` this or `SPContext.Current.Web.Url`

Answer (score 0):

Site URL in a project you set for the possibility to deploy solution to SharePoint via Visual Studio. If you want to get current Web url from code you can use  SPContext:
SPContext.Current.Site.Url - for the site collection url,
SPContext.Current.Web.Url - for the current Web url.